# Differential and derivative of $X^{-2}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Determine the differential and derivative of $F(X) = X^{-2}$ in which the variable X is an
n x n-matrix.

I computed the differential by using the product rule. So I first wrote
$$
f(X)= X^{-1} X^{-1}
$$, 
so 
$$
d(f(x))= d(X^{-1})(X^{-1}) + (X^{-1})d(X^{-1}) = (-X^{-1})d(X)(X^{-1})(X^{-1}) -(X^{-1})(X^{-1})d(X)(X^{-1}).
$$ Did I compute this correctly? And how do I find the derivative now? Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit: I computed the derivative and I think it should be -((X^-2)' tensor (X^-1)) -((X^-1)'tensor(X^-2)). Could anyone give any feedback on whether I did this correctly (a prime denotes a transpose)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map $f$ is the composition of $g(X)=X^2$ and $h(X)=X^{-1}$.

The differential of the first one is
$$
dg_X(H)=XH+HX
$$
and for the second one, it is
$$
dh_X(H)=-X^{-1}HX^{-1}.
$$

By the chain rule,
$$
df_X(H)=dh_{g(X)}\circ dg_X(H)=dh_{X^2}(XH+HX)
$$
$$
=-X^{-2}(XH+HX)X^{-2}=-X^{-1}HX^{-2}-X^{-2}HX^{-1}.
$$

So yes, you are correct. But your notations are slightly confusing. Only slightly.

Comment: Hahaha ok, thanks a lot. And now how do I find the derivative? By vectorising?

Comment: Could you please check if I computed the derivative correctly?

Comment: @user48288 Yes, you are correct. Provided $-X^{-1}d(X)X^{-2}$ means $H\longmapsto -X^{-1}HX^{-2}$. But I believe that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. Thanks a lot. I think I finally start to become acquainted with computing these kinds of differentials and derivatives :). Thanks a lot again for all your help recently :).

Comment: @user48288 You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You computed the differential correctly
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\X{X^{-1}}
\def\XT{X^{-T}}
F &= X^{-2} \qiq dF = -\LR{\X\,dX\:F + F\:dX\:\X} \\
}$$
so let's continue from there.

Since a matrix-by-matrix gradient is a fourth-order tensor, let's introduce the fourth-order *identity* tensor, which coincidentally is the component-wise self-gradient of any matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\grad{X}{X} = \E \qiq \grad{X_{ij}}{X_{kl}} = \E_{ijkl} = \d_{ik}\,\d_{jl}  }$$
We'll also use a colon to denote the *double-dot* product
$$\eqalign{
\def\B{{\cal B}}
C &= \B:A \qiq C_{ij} = \sum_{k}\sum_{l}\,\B_{ijkl}\,A_{kl} \\
}$$
The two most interesting properties of the $\E$ tensor are
$$\eqalign{
A:\E &= \E:A = A \\
AXB &= \LR{A\E B^T}:X \\\\
}$$
Applying these ideas to the differential expression yields the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
dF &= -\LR{\X\E F^T + F\E \XT}:dX \\
\grad{F}{X} &= -\LR{\X\E F^T + F\E \XT} \\\\
}$$
A different approach, which avoids tensors, is to [vectorize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the differential expression
$$\eqalign{
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
f &= \vc{F},\qquad x = \vc{X} \\
df &= -\LR{F^T\otimes\X + \XT\otimes F} dx \\
\grad{f}{x} &= -\LR{F^T\otimes\X + \XT\otimes F} \\
}$$